# For in loop creating new Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 `pd.DataFrame` and I want to apply the same operation (with a loop) creating 3 new DataFrames.

```
d = {}
dfs=[d10,d11,acc]
for i in dfs:
    a = (i.groupby('Variable').cumcount()).reset_index()
    d[i] = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I've tried to save it in a dictionary buT the error I've obtained is:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: You are trying to use a DataFrame as a dictionary key.  That's not allowed.  You can store them in a list, or you can use an integer as a key, but you can't use a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I store them in a list? @TimRoberts

Comment: You already have `dfs` as a list.  Just create `d = []` and do `d.append( pd.DataFrame(a) )`.  Now the two lists are in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've solved it @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a list. Not in a dictionary.

```
dfs=[d10,d11,acc]
for i in dfs:
    a = (i.groupby('Variable').cumcount()).reset_index()
    d.append( pd.DataFrame(a) )
```

Then, for calling each DataFrame:

> d[0]-->d10

> d[1]-->d11

> d[2]-->acc